# Static variables in flutter widgets, bad idea?

Tags: flutter, static, widget

Is making static variables in a flutter widget a bad idea?
For example, If I have a top stateful widget with a scaffold and I pass a globalKey to the scaffold like this:

```
class DemoScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  createState() => DemoScreenState();
}

class DemoScreenState extends State<DemoScreen> {
final scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: scaffoldKey,
      body: Builder(
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return ...
```

I would want to access that key in a widget lower in the tree, could I make this `final scaffoldKey` `static` and access this key with `DemoScreenState.scaffoldKey`? Or is that a bad idea? And why?

Why would you also define your final variables in the `DemoScreenState` and not in the `DemoScreen`? Is it just to make your code more readable by not having to use `widget.scaffoldKey`?

Comment: Yes. It's a bad idea. You should instead use Inheritedwidget, like provider

Comment: what is the reason? just for using the scaffoldstate is that okay?

Answer (score 0):

1 - DemoScreenState should be private like this _DemoScreenState

2 - only if you want to access GlobalKeyScaffoldState>() from another widget yes, put it in Demo Screen and make it as static variable and use the widget.ScaffoldKey.

3 - everything you want to do in code just think about what make the code easy readable, more flexible and good at performance

I hope my comment help you